# Append child component to parent component in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I am searching for a clean way, [in a jquery `append`-like fashion](http://api.jquery.com/append/), to dynamically append an child component `child` to a parent component `parent`, every time a given event fires, so that, starting from:

```
<parent></parent>
```

I would get:

```
<parent>
   <child></child>
</parent>
```

Also, the component type of the child have to be considered unknown until the event happens.

I suppose the structure could be modelled like:

```
import { Component} from '@angular/core';
import { OnMyEvent} from 'onmyevent';

@Component({selector: 'odd-child'})
export class OddChildComponent {}  

@Component({selector: 'even-child'})
export class EvenChildComponent {}    

@Component({selector: 'parent'})
export class ParentComponent implements OnMyEvent {    
  constructor() {}

  onMyEvent(n) {
    if (n%2==0){
      this.append(new EvenChildComponent())
    } else {
      this.append(new OddChildComponent())
    }
  }

}
```

Using jquery I would go about this in the following fashion:

```
<div id="parent"></div>
```

Script:

```
document.body.onmyevent = function(e, n) {
    if(n%2==0){
        child = $("div.even-child")
    } else {
        child = $("div.odd-child")
    }
    $("#parent").append(child)
}
```

And when the event with parameter `n=4` is fired I would achieve:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="even-child"></div>
</div>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what is your use case?

Comment: I would simply like to append an element to another one when the method `onMyEvent ` is called. Being used to [`jquery append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) I wanted to know what is the approach used in angular. Sadly, I have yet to find what I seek, yet I believe it to be an extremely simple thing.

Comment: maybe you can achieve what you want in another way

Comment: Ehm, yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: well that's why i asked what you are trying to do

Comment: I have extended my question, including an example showing how I would achieve something pretty similar to what I want using jquery.

Comment: you can do this using `ngIf` and `EventEmitter`

Comment: Could you extend your proposal in an answer?

Comment: As some have said, you could use `*ngIf*. Or you could use *ngFor* if you need more than one child and know which children elements you might want added.

Comment: `ngFor`, as I understand it, is not suited for this issue as different components could be added following a rule in the controller.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {EventEmitter, OnInit} from "@angular/core";
@Component({selector: 'parent'})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit{
  item = null
  showEvent: EventEmitter<string>;
  constructor() {
   this.showEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
  }
  ngOnInit(){
   this.showEvent.subscribe(item=> {
      this.item = item;
   })
  }

}

<parent>
   <child *ngIf="item === 'item type 1'"></child>
   <another-child *ngIf="item === 'item type 2'"></another-child>
</parent>
```

now to trigger that event you do: 
`this.showEvent.emit("item type 1")`
but i think you are going to use this event outside of the parent component, if so, you need a service

Comment: This approach assumes that I know the type of the child before the event happens. Also, how would you proceed to scale this approach when the event is called twice?

Comment: is the child is normal div or component? and again, im not asking how you want to do certain thing, im asking what you want to do

Comment: It would be a component, in the jquery example I used a div for demonstrative purposes.

Comment: Ok, but what about for `m` possible calls to the event and `k` possible child components? This approach does not scale.